# basic c++ program runs on only one core

Tags: c++

I m trying to do basics with parallel programming, but for some reason i can t get multiple cores to run my code (bellow). I m doing this in visual studio 2019, where the bellow code runs but only one core actually computes it. My computer has 4. I tried this with a different compiler (same code) and it worked. Does anyone have a suggestion what i should do to overcome this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << omp_get_max_threads() << endl;
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        cout << "hello"
             << " " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output for this (mind the typos if i made any writing this):

```
4
hello 0
```

Comment: Did you enable openmp in VS settings? Right click your project, go to properties => C/C++ => Language => Set Open MP Support to Yes, recompile and try again.

Comment: i didn t. Thanks for the tip, Ill try it now.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much for your help (wish i could at least upvote your answer).